# How can I have access to relational data in Parse using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, relational

Here is what I have:

I have a class named "News" as you can see in the image and another class named "Gallery"

[image: this is what I have in News Class]

[image: and this is the view after i click on view relations and I need to find out a way that can have access to here to retrieve data]

I retrieve columns data like this :

```
ATit = [] 
ADat = []
ACon = []
AIma = []
AGal = []
new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("News")).find({
                   success: function(results) { 
                   $.each(results, function (Items, Objects) {
                        ATit.push(Objects.attributes.Title)
                        ADat.push(Objects.attributes.Date)
                        ACon.push(Objects.attributes.Content)
                        AIma.push(Objects.attributes.Image.url())
                      })
                   }
                   })
```

but I can't retrieve data from **Gallery** column..
all I want is to put `image.url()` from Gallery into **AGal** array, as you can see in the image I have 4 images inside the Gallery which have Relation to **Gallery column** and I need to know how can I have access to it ?

Comment: You need to make another query. Something like: `var query = obj.relation('Gallery').query(); query.find().then(...)`.

Comment: thank you so much, it works in the way you said....

Comment: please write it as answer so i can mark your answer as correct answer :)